# My recycleView only call/count elements from screen

Tags: android

I have a problem to updae my recycle when updating scroll up/down.

I have 3 (Custom ítems with respect views) but my onBindViewHolder only calls 2, when I try down list, my list not update correctly aparently It makes a cut (0.2 sec)

I don't know why not update correctly with 3 (ítems with 3 images)

My holder :  (Why count 2?) but I when down, count 3 ...

```
public class CAPusheenAdapter_Fragment_0_7 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CAPusheenAdapter_Fragment_0_7.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<CustomItem_0_ALL> pusheenArrayList;
private int itemLayout;
private Context context;
DBHelper db ;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

public CAPusheenAdapter_Fragment_0_7(ArrayList<CustomItem_0_ALL> data, int itemLayout, Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView){
    setHasStableIds(true);
    this.       pusheenArrayList        = data;
    this.       itemLayout              = itemLayout;
    this.       context                 = context;
    db =        new                     DBHelper(context);
    this.       recyclerView            = recyclerView;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ArrayList<TextView>     allTextViews;
    //public TextView     text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7;
    public LinearLayout l1;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        int numOfTextViews=6;
        allTextViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();   allTextViews.add(0,null);
        l1 = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.l1);
        for(int i=1;i<=numOfTextViews;i++){
            allTextViews.add(i,Config.getViewsComplext(context,itemView, "text" + i));
        }

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //final int itemPosition = Fragment_0.recyclerView.getChildPosition(view); // todo SOO COOL LINE !
                final int itemPosition = recyclerView.getChildPosition(view); // todo SOO COOL LINE !
                //Toast.makeText(context, "No plantejada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //MainActivity.FragmentReutil2(new Class[]{Fragment_0_4_1.class}, 0, context);
            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public CAPusheenAdapter_Fragment_0_7.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
    Config.totalConfigFull2(context, itemLayoutView);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CAPusheenAdapter_Fragment_0_7.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    CustomItem_0_ALL pusheen = pusheenArrayList.get(position);

    ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
    texts.add(0,null);
    texts.add(1,pusheen.getText1());
    texts.add(2,pusheen.getText2());
    texts.add(3,pusheen.getText3());
    texts.add(4,pusheen.getText4());
    texts.add(5,pusheen.getText5());
    texts.add(6,pusheen.getText6());

    for ( int i = 1 ; i < viewHolder.allTextViews.size() ; i+=1 ){

        if(texts.get(i).length()>0){
            viewHolder.allTextViews.get(i).setText(texts.get(i));
            viewHolder.allTextViews.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            viewHolder.allTextViews.get(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    //viewHolder.l1.setBackgroundResource(pusheen.getImg());

    int w  =Config.getWigthHeightScreen(context)[0];
    int h  =Config.getWigthHeightScreen(context)[1];

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w, (int) (h/2.5));

    viewHolder.l1.setBackgroundResource(pusheen.getImg());
    viewHolder.l1.setLayoutParams(lp);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.pusheenArrayList.size();
}
```

}

**Note : only call/count elements from screen not call out elements, only call when you move list up/down**

Comment: Any idea ? or this problem occurred to new versions ?  I see that Android 6.0 says ...ListViews + fast ... I don't know if is my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found problem :

This is the problem : and solution

[AsyncTask loading image RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600630/asynctask-loading-image-recyclerview)